# How to pass double value from html input to C# controller

Tags: c#, html

I have created an input i html to pass double value into the controller:

The Controller method has the parameter, double value)

But it is only working with integer value in the input field anyway.
If a value of 88.9 is typed into the input field above it pass 0 to the controller, why?

How to pass double parameter from html input to the controller?

Comment: using HTML: <input type="number" name="value" step="0.1"/> but it not working

Comment: check decimal format in region setting and see whether it's `,` or `.` or `/`

Comment: Post a valid example of what you did already.

Comment: @JohanLång You might want to look at questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536790/asp-net-mvc-5-double-value-always-0-0-in-controller or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908503/c-sharp-mvc-controller-cannot-get-decimal-or-double-values-from-ajax-post-reques since it might be a CultureInfo problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I just added the line in Startup.cs:  
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");